# associative array from javascript to activex object

Tags: javascript, com, activex, atl

I need to pass an associative array from Javascript to a C++ activex control in IE6+. It seems a shame to write my own type for something so standard. It doesn't have to work with native JS objects, I can use a custom associative array type if I need.

I've been googling for a couple days and there isn't a lot of information on this subject. COM and ATL have to have this already, don't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150913075623/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/22/53061.aspx) by [Eric Lippert](https://web.archive.org/web/20230922200905/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/) may shed some light on how it could be done from C++. Take a look at his comments about a Javascript array being a [Dispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch) object. As such you could get the DISPIDs and call [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-invoke) on each one. Another option is to convert the Javascript array to a `SafeArray` using [VBArray](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984) (and a little VBScript), or you could just use the [Scripting.Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.85%29) COM object, which is the equivalent of an associative array. A few resources are below.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david.wang/howto-convert-between-jscript-array-and-vb-safe-array)

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0600__MS-JScript/DictionaryKeys.htm